# How to change the running status of a Cnosdb node

Tags: cnosdb

Does Cnosdb provide heartbeat detection between node and meta and the function of changing node status. For example, if the node has not communicated with meta for a period of time, the node needs to be taken offline.

I checked the official documentation of cnosdb. It seems that there is no such function， I hope Cnosdb can realize this function.